# set TextBox value using Jquery where it has TextMode="date" property set

Tags: jquery, validation, date, textbox

I have this textbox with textmode property set to date:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateBox" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

I got a date string I retrieved using AJAX from my XML file to my JS function:

```
$docDate = $(this).attr("date");
```

Now I have validated the date when it was enterred to the XML file, so I just want to set my textbox value to the date I got from the XML file, that is now $docDate.

How do I do that? I've tried using .val($docDate) function and other stuff and it's not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

btw, the textBox looks like this:
[image: textbox set to date mode]

as requested, here is the whole code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ControlPanel.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlPanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/site_icon.ico" />
    <title>מבואת המזכירות</title>
    <link href="Style/CPStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Style/RecordsStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/Jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#idBox").change(function () {
                selectedID = $('#idBox').val();
                // מציאת נתוני הרשומה המבוקשת באמצעות אג'קס
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "LobbyFiles.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: xmlParser
                });
            });
            function formatDateForInput(date) {
                var year = date.getFullYear();
                var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                return String.format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year, month, day);
            }
            function xmlParser(xml) {
                // מציאת מספר רשומה מבוקש
                $docId = $('#idBox').val();
                // אתחול משתנים
                $docName = "";
                $docType = "";
                $docDate = "";
                $docLink = "";
                $docAuthor = "";
                $docPlce = "";

                foundNode = false;
                // מציאת הרשומה בעלת מספר רשומה המבוקש
                $(xml).find("link").each(function () {

                    $nodeId = $(this).attr("id");
                    if ($nodeId == $docId) {
                        foundNode = true;
                        // הכנסת ערכי הרשומה למשתנים המאותחלים
                        $docName = $(this).text();
                        $docType = $(this).attr("type");
                        $docAuthor = $(this).attr("author");
                        $docDate = $(this).attr("date");
                        $docLink = $(this).attr("url");
                        $docPlce = $(this).attr("place");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                // לאחר הלולאה אם לא נמצאה רשומה בעלת מספר זה, יחזיר את הערך לאפס ויודיע למשתמש
                // במידה ויימצא - ייקח את כל הערכים הנמצאים במשתנים ויכניסם לטופס
                if (foundNode) {
                    $("#DocNameBox").val($docName);
                    $("#urlBox").val($docLink);
                    $("#placeBox").val($docPlce);
                    $("#authorNameBox").val($docAuthor);

                    switch ($docType) {
                        case "protocol":
                            $("#typeList").val("protocol");
                            break;
                        case "schedule":
                            $("#typeList").val("schedule");
                            break;
                        case "olympus":
                            $("#typeList").val("olympus");
                            break;
                        case "formalPaper":
                            $("#typeList").val("formalPaper");
                            break;
                    }

                    var id = "<%= dateBox.ClientID %>";
                    alert(id);
                    $("#" + id).val(formatDateForInput($docDate));
                }
                else {
                    $("#idBox").val("0");
                    alert("מספר רשומה מבוקש לא נמצא!");
                }
            }
            // פונקציה זו מקבלת את נתוני הרשומה ומטמיעה אותם בפקדי הדף
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div> <a href="Records.aspx"><img class="linkIcon" src="Images/back.ico" /></a>
        <a href="Home.html"> <img id="homeIcon" src="Images/home.ico" class="linkIcon" /></a>
            <div id="main_wrapper">
                <h1>לוח ניהול המבואה</h1>
                <h5 id="details">
                    ניתן להוסיף רשומה חדשה למבואה - או לחילופין לעדכן רשומה קיימת. 
                     על מנת להוסיף רשומה חדשה - השאר את מספר המסמך על 0. 
                     כדי לעדכן רשומה קיימת - הכנס את מספר הרשומה שברצונך לעדכן.
                            </h5>              
            <asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        מספר מסמך:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="idBox" runat="server" TextMode="Number" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        שם המסמך:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DocNameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        סוג המסמך:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="typeList" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="מסמך רשמי" Value="formalPaper" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="פרוטוקול/סיכום ישיבה" Value="protocol" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="מרכז תנועה/עולימפוס" Value="olympus" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="לוח זמנים" Value="schedule" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        קישור:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="urlBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>נכתב ע"י:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="authorNameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>מקום כתיבה (להשאיר ריק אם לא במחנה):</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="placeBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>בתאריך:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dateBox" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="הוסף נתונים לקובץ XML" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your code which used .val($docDate)

Comment: you'll need to use the client Id of dateBox if you are using .val or use [client id mode static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It does require a specific format to work - I've literally just done the same thing myself.  Here's what I used...

```
function formatDateForInput(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return String.format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year, month, day);
}
```

That function simply forces the date into the correct format *yyyy-mm-dd*

You can then apply it to the element like this...

```
$("[id$=dateBox]").val(formatDateForInput($docDate));
```

Here's an example of it working and failing, with different date formats...

http://jsfiddle.net/CMxGR/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `clientID` to get the exact element. Then only you can use `.val("new value")` to set the value. Try with this code,

```
var id="<%= dateBox.ClientID %>";
$("#"+id).val("new date here");
```

Comment: The problem isn't selecting the correct element.  The value *has* to be in a specific format for the control to accept it.  See my answer to see what I mean.  Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/CMxGR/1/

Comment: @Archer Oh i see. I've confused reading the point "I just want to set my textbox value to the date I got from the XML file"

Comment: @user2396866 does it sets any value? Can you share your whole code?

Comment: I tried Archer's example and it worked for me. The other examples haven't. I'll share my code in a second yeah

Comment: I've added the code. A lot of the comments and text are in Hebrew, I hope you wouldn't mind :)

Comment: @user2396866 does Archer's code worked for you? or still have you facing the issue?